# Postfix Limit Emails and connections

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, bulk

I want to use Bulk Send Mode Logic in Postfix With Connection Per Connection and what I'v tried hasn't worked.

Here is Bulk Logic in Telnet:

```
~ telnet example.com 25
~ ehlo example.com
~ mail from: username@example.com
**In this place i want to browse 10 mails then send data**
~ rcpt to: mailA@hotmail.com
250 recipient OK
~ rcpt to: mailB@hotmail.com  
250 recipient OK
~ rcpt to: mailC@hotmail.com
250 recipient OK
~ rcpt to: mailD@hotmail.com
250 recipient OK
~ rcpt to: mailE@hotmail.com
250 recipient OK
~ DATA
~ QUIT
```

This is exactly what I want to implement in Postfix.